# How to build an sdist with pip?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging, flit

I'm in the process of converting my projects to use `flit` as their build backend using `pyroject.toml` as defined in PEP517.

I still have some projects that will continue to use `setuptools` as their build backend. Some projects may not be PEP 517 compliant and will use the legacy `setup.py` build system.

I'm using the latest `pip` (20.1) as the build frontend, regardless of whether the build backend for a particular project is `setuptools` or `flit`. However, I can't figure out how to generate an sdist with `pip`.

I can generate a wheel with `pip`, regardless of the build backend

```
$ pip wheel . -w dist --no-deps
```

But there doesn't appear to be a similar `pip` command to generate an `sdist`, even though all build backends must support creating sdists, as defined in PEP517.

Shouldn't all build front-ends support building `sdist`'s? Should I be using another tool? I'd like to use the same command to build all of my projects regardless of what their build backend is.

Comment: `pip` doesn't support building sdists yet, related issue: [#6041](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6041).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python Packaging Guide [recommends](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#generating-distribution-archives) building packages using the new `build` library maintained by the same Python Packaging Authority that maintains `pip`.

https://github.com/pypa/build

```
python -m build . --sdist
```